# Strange behavior with border in content

Tags: html, css

Please look at following

[Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/161/)
[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/162/)
    HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="space">
    </div>  
    <div class="item">
      DIV1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
.content {
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.space {
  margin-top:80px;
 border:1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:50px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The only difference is the border statement in content class but output is different.

Can you please explain what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [margin collapsing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). The border, when present, prevents the top margin of the `.space` from collapsing. Without the border, it collapses with the top margin of all its ancestors including `body` (which is the 'base' for the position of `.item`), causing them to move 80px down.

Comment: how can achieve the same behavior as with border present but without the statement in content...I will read up on aticle.

Comment: Instead of red I used transparent but thats a hack. Whats the right way?

Comment: You can replace margin-top for `.space` with padding-top, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`.item` is getting position absolute with `top` as `80px` relative to `.cointainer` DIV. Element with position as absolute will position itself with reference to its parent whose position is defined as `relative` or to BODY element. In your case top most parent element `.container` is having `positon: relative` so for element `.item` `top: 80px` will be calculated from top of `.container` and since `.item` is positioned as absolute it will contained only withing its parent with `position: relative` or body element, so in your case its a top most element `.container`